# Does this ICACLS command also apply the settings onto childitems?

Tags: icacls

I'm trying to use ICACLS in powershell to set a few permissions.

Does this ICACLS command also apply the permission onto childitems in the same run?

```
icacls "D:\Folder" /grant "Domain\ADGroup":(OI)(CI)RX
```

If so, is there a way to turn this off? Can't I set the permissions just on the parent folder?

I'm completely resetting each childitem afterwards anyway so that every messy permission/owner gets removed and each childitem inherits the correct permissions again.

But this would take the double amount of time if the previous command already runs through each childitem and applies the permission I specified.

Comment: This isn't powershell, it's cmd and icalcs (legacy appl.). Did you try? A few test folders, reading `icacls /?` and verifying using Properties->Security->Advanced would go a long way. :-)

Comment: `(OI)` stands for "object inherit" (files) and `(CI)` stands for "container inherit" (folders). You probably want to remove them both, if that's really what you need. ACLs can be very tricky at times, be careful ;)

Comment: @Poorkenny That's inheritance, which he wants. He doesn't want direct ACEs on every item.

Comment: @FrodeF. Good point. Then I don't think there's anything to change. IIRC you need to specify /T if you want to recursively apply on subfolders.

Comment: @FrodeF. yes, exactly. i do want inheritance to be set but not to already apply the permission onto childitems in the same run since i'm resetting them individually later on. i maybe should have clarified this a little better. sorry about that. and yes i did quite some testing :) but i couldn't figure out how to achieve what i want right now.

Answer (score 2):

No, the permissions are only applied to `D:\Folder`, but subfolders and files will inherit the permissions as you've specified.

If you'd used `/T` it would set the permissions on each and every file, so try to avoid that.

> **/t**  Performs the operation on all specified files in the current
>   directory and its subdirectories.

[Icacls](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525(v=ws.11).aspx)

Comment: yeah, i'm aware of that switch. but does it do the same as using `/reset` on each childitem? or does it just apply the new permission i specified on the parent folder onto all childitems and leave everything else as is? my goal is to set one new group with read & execute permission on the parent folder and then recursively **reset** each childitem. i want to make sure every other permission i did not specify at the parent folder gets removed. but then how can I apply the permission onto the parent folder with inheritance without already applying this onto childitems?

Comment: No, `icacls "D:\Folder" /grant "Domain\ADGroup":(OI)(CI)RX` will not reset subfolders. It will only add the permission at `Folder` and let the childitems inherit them. If you used `/T` it would have applied to all subitems directly also, while keeping the rest as is. You need to run reset by itself before or after adding the permission. Again, did you try it? Or read the help at the link I provided? It would take you 3 folders and 5 min to test this yourself, that's the best way to learn. :-)

Comment: Yes, as I said, I did quite some testing and also took a look at your link. I'm mainly asking here if there is a way to apply the new permission without having it run through all childitems immediately. But it seems like this is not possible. Thanks for your help either way :)

Comment: I don't understand. You ask specifically to remove (reset) old permissions on all child items, but you do not want it to "run through all childitems". To reset permissions on all items, you need let it touch all items, it can't remove what it can't see. Then you apply the single permission (in your question) to the top level. Good luck

Comment: I think you misunderstand. It doesn't matter what I do first (set new permission or reset each childitem). It will run through all childitems both times. What I'm trying to achieve is though only **one** run through all childitems in which each childitem is reset and also inherits my new applied permission. but this is only possible when `icacls "D:\Folder" /grant "Domain\ADGroup":(OI)(CI)RX` does not bequeath its settings immediately to all childitems after running the command. but again, it seems like this is not possible.